# 3 Responsive DIV Boxes Side by Side - Not Staying Together

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi i need help figuring this out. I have 3 divs that need to stay side by side regardless of how big or small the screen is, but the problem is that, once the screen's width reaches below 400px, then the last div goes under the others. How can I make them stay inline and at the same time responsive and centered without getting crazy with media queries? Please help. **[HERE'S A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/32hcm/)**

CSS:

```
.box{
    background-color: coral;
    width: 30%;    
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.text{
    padding: 10px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to fix this would be to wrap the divs in a container, and give that container a `white-space:nowrap;text-align:center` rule. Then change the divs from floating to `display:inline-block;`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/32hcm/6/)**

```
.box {
    background-color: coral;
    width: 30%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px 0;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.text {
    padding: 10px 0;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
#container {
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: by implementing this, i still see a problem, everything goes to the right. It needs to be viewed

Comment: meaning, when the screen's width is small, all the boxes should still be viewed. With your code, the last box ,on the right, is no longer able to be viewed.

Comment: this works. Please update your answer to show the code, and I will give you the check. thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a safer responsive layout, work with `display:table` on a wrapper div, and change the box to `display:table-cell`. For the padding, add a middle div, and set the width in percentual value. Also, you won't even need to set the box width.

http://jsfiddle.net/32hcm/9/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    background-color: coral;
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.text{
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your fixed margin of `10px`. Change it to percent value, and adjust the width percentual also, and it will work fine.

```
.box{
    background-color: coral;
    width: 28%;    
    float:left;
    margin:1%;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.text{
    padding: 10px 0;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/32hcm/5/

Comment: this works, but it is still not centered. They all need to be centered

Comment: no problem.. though, the boxes are still not centered. I need them all to be centered in the middle of the screen. Should i wrap them all inside another div?

Comment: Yes, but I would change the approach then... always best to work with `display:table`. I've added another answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use **table-cell**

and have a container to be set to 100%:

```
.core {width: 100%; display: table; border-spacing: 10px;}

.box{
    background-color: coral;
    width: 32.03125%; 
    float:none;
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/JF2gG/)**