# Adjust orders for responsive layout with 3 floating divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 3 grid responsive layout as seen in the diagram attached. On a full sized screen, the divs should look like the one on the left, and when scaled down the one on the right.

I can easily move down div B below div C using "float: left" once the page is small enough, it will naturally drop below div C.

So the problem I am facing is how to actually get div C to go below B while B goes in between A and C like the right of the diagram?

- I need the divs coded in order of A, then B, then finally C
- A's height is fixed
- B's height is variable
- C's height is variable

I am stuck at this stage: https://jsfiddle.net/45x54w2g/
I can't figure out how to move C down to the bottom left right below div A - 
without leaving a gap .. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!
Body Code:

```
<div id="A" style="width: 40%; height: 300px;">
  A
</div>  

<div id="B" style="width: 55%; height: 600px;">
  B
</div>  


<div id="C" style="width: 40%">  
  C
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  min-width: 400px;
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;  
}
```

[image: Diagram showing how the divs should arrange after sizing down]

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637501/3-responsive-div-boxes-side-by-side-not-staying-together

Comment: For the height part, what about it in the left diagram? For the right diagram, i guess you want the 3 blocks takes 100% height for the container, right?

Comment: It is!!!!!!!!! http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/25/

Comment: If flexbox is an option, there's an order property that will let you define the order of your divs

Comment: @Pangloss for the left diagram, the heights on A and C are mostly fixed, however- B a variable depending on how much text there is

Comment: using float: left doesn't actually work since when B is too short, C might end up right below B ... and clearfix right after B will end up similar to what i already have in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the markup slightly, added a container, moved div B to the top, and float it to the right. For the second structure, I used `@media` + `flexbox`. See the following demo, run the snippet and click "Full page" to view the other layout, or use the jsfiddle demo.

https://jsfiddle.net/ydv01r9e/

```css
.a, .b, .c {
  width: 50%;
}

.b {
  float: right;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .a, .b, .c {
    width: auto;
  }
  .a {
    order: 1;
  }
  .b {
    order: 2;
  }
  .c {
    order: 3;
  }
}

.a {background: lime;}
.b {background: orange;}
.c {background: hotpink;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="b">b<br>b<br>b</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this works! but is there a way to have div 'b' float left instead of right and still make the entire layout work?

Comment: Unless you add a container to div A and C, but there will be troubles with the flexbox part. Why do you need float left by the way?

Comment: i m pretty bad working with float:right - i m trying to have div "b" anchored to the right of "a" and "c" with about 30px of padding to the right so it complicates things alittle

i tried padding-right : 10% on div "b" - but that obviously causes some problems on the overall layout (such as b flushing down "a" and "c" altogether when the page is sized down)

Comment: or maybe, is there a way to make "a" and "c" a fixed width like 460px? instead of using percentage values? since i really only need "b" to be responsive

Comment: If you need some `padding`, also add `box-sizing:border-box;` together.

Comment: wow , i never knew such a function existed in css! thanks you pangloss for all the help! i cant thank you more for getting me out of this roadblock!